# Tough T-SQL To Left Join?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've got a table of ExchangeRates that have a countryid and an exchangeratedate something to this effect:

```
ExchangeRateID   Country   ToUSD      ExchangeRateDate
1                  Euro     .7400     2/14/2011
2                  JAP      80.1900   2/14/2011
3                  Euro     .7700      7/20/2011
```

Notice there can be the same country with a different rate based on the date...so for instance above Euro was .7400 on 2/14/2011 and now is .7700 7/20/2011.

I have another table of line items to list items based on the country..in this table each line item has a date associated with it.  The line item date should use the corresponding date and country based on the exchange rate.  So using the above data if I had a line item with country Euro on 2/16/2011 it should use the euro value for 2/14/2011 and not the value for 7/20/2011 because of the date (condition er.ExchangeRateDate <= erli.LineItemDate).  This would work if I only had one item in the table, but imagine I had a line item date of 8/1/2011 then that condition (er.ExchangeRateDate <= erliLineItemDate) would return multiple rows hence my query would fail...

```
SELECT     
    er.ExchangeRateID, 
    er.CountryID AS Expr1, 
    er.ExchangeRateDate, 
    er.ToUSD, 
    erli.ExpenseReportLineItemID, 
    erli.ExpenseReportID, 
    erli.LineItemDate
FROM         
    dbo.ExpenseReportLineItem AS erli 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.ExchangeRate AS er 
ON er.CountryID = erli.CountryID 
AND DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, er.ExchangeRateDate), 0) <= DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, 
                      erli.LineItemDate), 0)
WHERE     (erli.ExpenseReportID = 196)
```

The issue with this left join...is because the dates are <= the line item date so it returns many records, I would have to somehow do this but dont know how.

The LineItem tables has multiple records and each record could have its own CountryID:

```
Item            Country      ParentID    LineItemDate
Line Item 1      Euro           1           2/14/2011
Line Item 2      US             1           2/14/2011
Line Item3       Euro           1           2/15/2011
```

So there are three records for ParentID (ExpenseReportID) = 1.  So then I take those records and join the ExchangeRate table where the Country in my line item table = the country of the exchange rate table (that part is easy) BUT the second condition I have to do is the:

```
  AND DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, er.ExchangeRateDate), 0) <= DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, 
                          erli.LineItemDate), 0)
```

But here is where the issue is because that will return multiple rows from my exchange rate table because euro is listed twice.

Comment: Im crossing my fingers for a t-sql expert here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but as I understand it the "dumb" solution to your problem is  to use A ROW_NUMBER function and outer filter with your existing "returns too many entries" query (this can also be done with a CTE, but I prefer the derived table syntax for simple cases like this):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT     
        er.ExchangeRateID, 
        er.CountryID AS Expr1, 
        er.ExchangeRateDate, 
        er.ToUSD, 
        erli.ExpenseReportLineItemID, 
        erli.ExpenseReportID, 
        erli.LineItemDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExpenseReportID, ExpenseReportLineItemID ORDER BY ExchangeRateDate DESC) AS ExchangeRateOrderID
    FROM dbo.ExpenseReportLineItem AS erli 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ExchangeRate AS er 
        ON er.CountryID = erli.CountryID 
            AND DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, er.ExchangeRateDate), 0) 
                <= DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, erli.LineItemDate), 0)
    WHERE (erli.ExpenseReportID = 196)
        --For reasonable performance, it would be VERY nice to put a filter
        -- on how far back the exchange rates can go here:
        --AND er.ExchangeRateDate > DateAdd(Day, -7, GetDate())
) As FullData
WHERE ExchangeRateOrderID = 1
```

Sorry if I misunderstood, otherwise hope this helps!

Comment: This seems to not return anything.

Comment: Fair enough - there was a typo on the partition by, but not sure that explains it - still shouldn't have returned nothing :)

Comment: This looks to be the best solution that has worked for me.  I thought Lieven's solution was interesting however, his condition of <= and >= was displaying no rows...So this worked actually!

Answer (score 1):

It would make your life a lot easier if you could add an additional column to your ExchangeRates table called (something like)

```
ExchangeRateToDate
```

A separate process could update the previous entry when a new one was added.

Then, you could just query for LineItemDate >= ExhangeRateDate and <= ExchangeRateToDate

(treating the last one, presumably with a null ExchangeRateToDate, as a special case).

Answer (score 1):

I would create an in memory table creating an ExchangeRate table with ExchangeRateDates From & To.
All that's left to do after this is joining this CTE in your query instead of your ExchangeRate table and add a condition where the date is `between`the date from/to.

#### SQL Statement

```
;WITH er AS (
    SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY er1.ExchangeRateID ORDER BY er2.ExchangeRateDate DESC)
            , er1.ExchangeRateID
            , er1.Country
            , ExchangeRateDateFrom = ISNULL(DATEADD(d, 1, er2.ExchangeRateDate), 0)
            , ExchangeRateDateTo = er1.ExchangeRateDate
            , er1.ToUSD
    FROM    @ExchangeRate er1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @ExchangeRate er2
                ON  er1.Country = er2.Country
                    AND er1.ExchangeRateDate >= er2.ExchangeRateDate
                    AND er1.ExchangeRateID > er2.ExchangeRateID     
)
SELECT  er.ExchangeRateID, 
        er.CountryID AS Expr1, 
        er.ExchangeRateDateTo, 
        er.ToUSD, 
        erli.ExpenseReportLineItemID, 
        erli.ExpenseReportID, 
        erli.LineItemDate
FROM    dbo.ExpenseReportLineItem AS erli 
        LEFT JOIN er ON er.CountryID = erli.CountryID 
                        AND DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, er.ExchangeRateDateTo), 0) <= DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, erli.LineItemDate), 0)
                        AND DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, er.ExchangeRateDateFrom), 0) >= DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, erli.LineItemDate), 0)
WHERE   (erli.ExpenseReportID = 196)
        and er.rn = 1
```

#### Test script

```
DECLARE @ExchangeRate TABLE (
    ExchangeRateID INTEGER
    , Country VARCHAR(32)
    , ToUSD FLOAT
    , ExchangeRateDate DATETIME
)   

INSERT INTO @ExchangeRate 
VALUES  (1, 'Euro', 0.7400, '02/14/2011')
        , (2, 'JAP', 80.1900, '02/14/2011')
        , (3, 'Euro', 0.7700, '07/20/2011')     
        , (4, 'Euro', 0.7800, '07/25/2011')     

;WITH er AS (
    SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY er1.ExchangeRateID ORDER BY er2.ExchangeRateDate DESC)
            , er1.ExchangeRateID
            , er1.Country
            , ExchangeRateDateFrom = ISNULL(DATEADD(d, 1, er2.ExchangeRateDate), 0)
            , ExchangeRateDateTo = er1.ExchangeRateDate
            , ToUSD = er1.ToUSD
    FROM    @ExchangeRate er1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @ExchangeRate er2
                ON  er1.Country = er2.Country
                    AND er1.ExchangeRateDate >= er2.ExchangeRateDate
                    AND er1.ExchangeRateID > er2.ExchangeRateID     
)
SELECT  *
FROM    er
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Cool - I'm guessing this could be much more efficient than the ROW_NUMBER or correlated subquery solutions when you're selecting a large set of expense report line items?

Comment: Hmm it is complaining about two invalid column names ExchangeRateDate and ToUSD...

Comment: @oJM86o - sorry, been away. The missing columns have been added would you still be interested.

Comment: @Tao - on a large set, it would indeed be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try using a [table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to get to your TOP 1 and then JOIN to the table expression. Does that make sense? Hope this helps.

Comment: I cant do this as in my lineitem table I may have multiple line items each with a different country, so If I used TOP 1 in a CTE then I'd lose that join in the missing country...

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using one or more CTEs. This earlier SO question should have the needed building blocks :
[How can you use SQL to return values for a specified date or closest date < specified date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373287/how-can-you-use-sql-to-return-values-for-a-specified-date-or-closest-date-speci/5375100#5375100)

Note that you have to modify this to your own schema, and also filter out results that are closer but in the future.
I hope this helps, but if not enough then I'm sure I can post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as an correlated subquery that will give you a table with the most recent exchange values for a given date (indicated in a comment):

```
SELECT * 
FROM er
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT CountryID, MAX(ExchangeRateDate) AS ExchangeRateDate
        FROM er
        WHERE ExchangeRateDate <= '9/1/2011' 
            -- the above is the date you will need to correlate with the main query...
        GROUP BY Country
    ) iq
    ON iq.Country = er.Country AND er.ExchangeRateDate = iq.ExchangeRateDate
```

So the full query should look something like this:

```
SELECT     
    iq2.ExchangeRateID, 
    iq2.CountryID AS Expr1, 
    iq2.ExchangeRateDate, 
    iq2.ToUSD, 
    erli.ExpenseReportLineItemID, 
    erli.ExpenseReportID, 
    erli.LineItemDate
FROM dbo.ExpenseReportLineItem AS erli 
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM ExchangeRate er
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT CountryID, MAX(ExchangeRateDate) AS ExchangeRateDate
                FROM ExchangeRate er
                WHERE ExchangeRateDate <= erli.LineItemDate 
                -- the above is where the correlation occurs...
                GROUP BY Country
            ) iq
            ON iq.Country = er.Country AND er.ExchangeRateDate = iq.ExchangeRateDate
    ) iq2
    ON er.CountryID = erli.CountryID 
        AND DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, iq2.ExchangeRateDate), 0) <= DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, erli.LineItemDate), 0)
    WHERE     (erli.ExpenseReportID = 196)
```

Comment: I'm curious to know whether the Row_Number solution or correlated subquery is more efficient... I'm guessing yours provides SQL server with more options for optimization, but correlated subqueries just feel so... wrong! :)

Comment: It really depends on the data topography.  I've had `ROW_NUMBER` work really well and really go off the rails, too.  If you don't like correlated subqueries, you could always try an equivalent CTE.  At least it would look cleaner!

Comment: I can understand this however it has a whole slew of errors...multi part identifier, etc etc...trying to fix it now so I am not discounting your answer.

Comment: Interesting.  I see a couple of problems, which I'll edit to fix.  It's also possible that the '*' in my inner `SELECT` is picking up columns in your schema that didn't get included in your sample data.  If you make it specific to the fields you actually need selected from `ExchangeRate` it might help as well.

Comment: @mwigdahl I tried to fix yours, but look at your inner where condition `ExchangeRateDate <= erli.LineItemDate` if you placed this in management studio and tried to run it you should get a `The multi-part identifier erli.lineitemdate could not be bound`.

Answer (score 0):

If i don't misunderstand what you want to do you could use an outer apply to get the latest exchange rate.

```
select *
from ExpenseReportLineItem erli
  outer apply (select top 1 *
               from ExchangeRates as er1
               where er1.Country = erli.Country and
                     er1.ExchangeRateDate <= erli.LineItemDate 
               order by er1.ExchangeRateDate desc) as er
```

Comment: Is there any difference between this and a correlated subquery (other than that it offends me less :))?

Comment: @Tao I can't really tell. This query is at least honest about what it does. "Get the latest rate for each line". But the query plan is not that stupid. At least not with the *very* tiny amount of sample data I used. I will gladly leave it to someone else (OP perhaps) to figure out/test what version is the most effective.